# Can I use the native 'fs' filesystem in Node.JS on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure

I've deployed a functioning bit of nodeJS code to Azure. It uses the Jade view engine, pulling in template via the fs file library:

```
function generateEmail(emailType, params, callback){
fs.readFile(__parentDir + '/emailTemplates/' + emailType + '.jade', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var fn = jade.compile(data);
    var body = fn({data: params, moment: moment});    //The data going in to the template
    callback(body);
});
```

}

It works fine locally on my Mac, but the rendered email templates show up as `<undefined></undefined>` when received from the Azure deployment. I'm afraid there's something funky on Azure where I can't use 'fs' to load files and might have to use Blobs instead.

Is this a limitation in Azure? Or could the problem be unrelated to this fs.ReadFile method?

As a sanity check, I deployed this up to Nodejitsu and it works fine.

Many thanks!

Comment: sorry but just wanted to comment on this. I was hugely excited about node.js on azure but have been disappointed by the gotchas I've seen that are incompatible with linux and windows in general on node.js. The community in general is leaning toward linux support rather than windows although its open source. I see npms that are specifically coded for linux or have caveats with using windows. I don't see this the other way around with the exception of azure npm related.

Comment: Thanks for the comment- I too have been wondering this same question. The Azure portal is some of the best web app design I have ever seen- absolutely stunning. Dropbox integration is ridiculously easy. I've had a gotcha here and there that drive me crazy because it's otherwise so good.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on all your points AND am a big fan of Azure. However, with Node.js I've decided to go pure linux approach so I can use the best of breed NPMs and have no worries.

Comment: @Hairgami_Master, if it still an issue: can you check version of Node.js on Azure and Nodejitsu - an issue might be related to very old Node.js version on Azure. You could also check if using `path.join()` along with `fs.readFile` (instead of building path by string concatenation) would not help. I've never had any issue when using `fs.ReadFile` on Azure.

Comment: @Tom thanks for your thoughts. What type of OS do you develop on? If you develop on Windows, it may be easier to transition to Azure. I'm not anywhere near this code right now, so I can't check. I was also having problems with moment.js, and read about some strangeness that happens running that library on a Windows OS. I love the Azure platform dashboard/pricing model/etc., I just wish it could run on Linux devices.

Comment: @Hairgami_Master I developed several Node.js applications on Windows Azure Cloud Services (worker roles - no iisnode module) - node 0.8.4 version. Did not have any issues with `fs` module. However, occasionally I was getting issues with `http` module during large files transfer. Also `moment` library (version "2.1.0") works very well on Azure for me. But I did use only a subset of its API so there might be some functions which cause some issues on Windows platform.

Answer (score 3):

This was exactly the problem I had with azure and Node.JS. The solution I found after digging with many node variables was to use __file.

As a quick way to test this you can add to your app.js something like :

```
// global
baseDir = __dirname;
```

Then you would have this global variable accessible from anywhere. ie inside the router folder.

```
var defaultFile = path.join(baseDir, 'sample.txt');
```

[__dirname](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) always return the directory name for the current file. If you define a variable with this value from a file in the root folder you will have the application base folder.I have implemented this and it's working i azure and heroku.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's definitely better to use `__dirname` and be explicit with the path. I ran into a similar issue where I was using a relative path locally and my app work expected, but was unable to find the same file with the same relative path on Azure. I changed it to use the `path` module and `__dirname` and it was resolved. Thanks, @guillem!

Comment: Ah man finally. It was so confusing for me, because I could see the file I wanted to load relative to the file I was importing, but it just kept on saying the file does not exist. Using an absolute path with your approach fixed it for me!