# Azure function able to read file on local but not working on remote

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, fs, azure-blob-storage

I would download file on local the create a stream to send it via an api call

```
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
  process.env.CONNEXION_STRING
);
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
  params.containerName
);
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(process.env.FILE_LOCATION); // get file from storage
let blobData;
var defaultFile = path.join(params.baseDir, `${params.reportName}.pbix`); // use path module
let stream;

try {
  blobData = await blobClient.downloadToFile(defaultFile);
  console.log(blobData);
  stream = fs.createReadStream(defaultFile);
} catch (error) {
  params.context.log(error);
  console.log(error);
}
var options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${params.groupId}/imports?datasetDisplayName=${params.reportName}`,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${params.accessToken} `,
  },
  formData: {
    "": {
      value: stream,
      options: {
        filename: `${params.reportName}.pbix`,
        contentType: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
//check if file keep in mem
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      params.context.log(error);

      reject(error);
    } else {
      params.context.log(response);
      resolve(response.body);
    }
    fs.unlinkSync(defaultFile);
  });
});
```

In local it's working like a charm but when I deploy my function on server I get this error.

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\importPbix\exampleName.pbix'
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242912/can-i-use-the-native-fs-filesystem-in-node-js-on-microsoft-azure) having same issue , that's why I user `path` module and passed __dirname to function `params.baseDir`.

Comment: It seems you're only downloading and saving to a file so that you can create a stream out of it. Why not save it to a buffer directly using [`downloadToBuffer(Buffer, number, number, BlobDownloadToBufferOptions)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#downloadToBuffer_Buffer__number__number__BlobDownloadToBufferOptions_) or simply [`download(number, number, BlobDownloadOptions)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#download_number__number__BlobDownloadOptions_)?

Comment: I have tried a similar functions but the api reject the data returned back from `bownloadTobuffer` I think that the output of it is not the same as `fs.createReadStream()` If you can provide an example that show how the get the same output as `fs` module that would be great

Comment: COuld you please check if you successfully create the file?

Comment: No the file does not get created on remote